# How to Apache run Windows console as administrator?

Tags: php, windows, apache, shell

I have a PHP script that runs one command. The command needs to be runned as administrator. If I run Windows console as administrator and execute the command it works perfectly, on the other hand if I run the script from Windows console as administrator using PHP console it works perfectly.

However if I run the PHP script using Apache server on my PC, my page never finish loading and it does not executes the command in rigth way. I have Apache running as a service and I change the user of Apache to administrator.

Do someone sees a problem with the way I´m doing things?

Comment: The command might not be able to run in a service context, or there might be a problem with the script that only exhibits when it is being run as a web page.  Without more information, we're not going to be able to help.